# WinRT: How to access parent's ItemsSource in DataTemplateSelector of ContentControl

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, contentcontrol, datatemplateselector

i need help for my WindowsStoreApp using XAML/C#.

Let's start with a very short explanation of my Problem, and if it's not clear enough, then you'll find very detailed information below :)

In short: I have a `ContentControl` within a `GridView`. The `GridView` has the `ItemsSource` set to a Collection. In my `ContentControl` i want to use a selfmade `DataTemplateSelector`. In it's `SelectTemplateCore`-method i need acces to the items of the `GridView`'s `ItemsSource` - how can i do that in WinRT?

In detail:

I want to display folders of the user's system, like the Picture's Library, connected USB devices and so on. Different types of folders shall get different icons. Some of the icons i have as XAML Path Data, and some as image files. The folders are stored in a Collection. This Collection (named "Ordner") is stored in the Page's Viewmodel. Each folder has a property (based on enum) that specifies its type. First i use a custom `DataTemplateSelector` to check whether the folder's type can be displayed via image or via path. It works perfectly.

The code for this is here...
I have a Page like this:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage [...]
    xmlns:common="using:De.Mms.DiplomSnma.Win8App.Common">
    <common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>
        <common:OrdnerDataTemplateSelector x:Key="ordnerTemplateSelector"
            TemplatePathquelle="{StaticResource PathquelleDataTemplate}"
            TemplateBildquelle="{StaticResource BildquelleDataTemplate}" />
    </common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>

    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Ordner}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ordnerTemplateSelector}" >
        [...]
    </GridView>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>


class OrdnerDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TemplateBildquelle { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TemplatePathquelle { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore
        (object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        OrdnerViewModel ordner = item as OrdnerViewModel;
        if (ordner.OrdnerTyp.Equals(EnumClass.OrdnerTyp.Sharepoint))
        {
            return TemplateBildquelle;
        }
        else
        {
            return TemplatePathquelle;
        }
    }
}
```

If the folder's icon is based on a Path, a `DataTemplate` called "PathquelleDataTemplate" in a `ResourceDictionary` is called. Within the `DataTemplate` is, besides other UI-elements my `ContentControl`. Here i wanted to use another custom made `DataTemplateSelector` to check again the folder's type and choose an according `DataTemplate`, which then contains the correct path and it's data. But of course i could not just use `item` in the overwritten `SelectTemplateCore(item, container)`. Without any `DataContext` the `item` is `null`. How can i reference the `ItemsSource` of my (parent-parent-)parent `GridView`? I'm totally failing with specifying the `DataContext`. Every piece of help i found is based on WPF and seems not working in WinRT. Or is there a completely different but better suited way to get access to the Collection?

Here is the DataTemplate "PathquelleDataTemplate" (in a ResourceDictionary).

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PathquelleDataTemplate">
    <Grid Height="160" Width="220">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="White">
            [...]
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource iconTemplateSelector}" />
                [...]
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And here just as an example one of the DataTemplates the DataTemplateSelector would choose:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BildOrdnerIconCCTemplate">
    <Path Fill="Black" Data="[...ThePathData...]"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance for every help and sorry, if my english sounds sometimes a bit strange :)

Comment: Your English was great! And your question structure was fantastic as well. Firstly, I would pass the `DataContext` of `PathquelleDataTemplate` in to the `ContentControl` like so: `<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource iconTemplateSelector}" Content="{Binding}"/>`. This way, the `iconTemplateSelector` should get an `Item` to process.

Comment: Oh really, it was that simple? *shame on me* ;) When first trying it seemed not to work, but then i noticed that the `SelectTemplateCore`-method is called twice for every element, first with `item=null`, but second with the item properly set... Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Content` to the `DataContext` being passed in to `PathquelleDataTemplate`, i.e.

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource iconTemplateSelector}" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

As you noted, `iconTemplateSelector` will get two items, null, then the property. The null is for when the template first is applied and the second is for when the binding is resolved.